# Redux - Why is loginStatus undefined when component first starts rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm learning Redux and have come across an issue that I have not encountered before when using React without redux. I'm trying to display a piece of my state inside one of my components name loginStatus. The reducer I have setup this state with has an initial state but whenever I try and launch the application I get the console error:

> Cannot read property 'loginStatus' of undefined

Here is my code:

**Component**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as authActions from './userAuthActions';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
        if(typeof(this.props.userAuthReducer) !== 'undefined') {
            test = this.props.userAuthReducer.loginStatus;
            console.log(test)
        } else {
            console.log("it's undefined")
        }
    return (
            <div className={"popup-logins " + this.props.userAuthReducer.loginStatus}>

      </div>
    );
  }


}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
        userAuthReducer:state.userAuthReducer
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators(authActions,dispatch);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

**userAuthActions.js**

```
export const loginUser = () => {
    return {
        type:'loginUser',
        loggedIn:true
    }
}
export const toggleRegLog = () => {
        return {
            type:'toggleRegLog'
        }
}
```

**userAuthReducer**

```
let initialState = {
    loginStatus: "not-logged-in"
    , toggleRegLog: 'login'
};
const userAuthReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case 'loginUser':
        let newState;
        if (action.loggedIn) {
            Object.assign({}, state, {
                loginStatus: "logged-in"
            })
        }
        else {
            Object.assign({}, state, {
                loginStatus: "not-logged-in"
            })
        }
        return newState;
        break;
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
export default userAuthReducer;
```

**combine reducers**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import userAuthReducer from './userAuthReducer';

function lastAction(state = null, action) {
  return action;
}

export default combineReducers({
  lastAction,userAuthReducer
});
```

What's strange is that I initially get a console.log of it's undefined" when I first start up the app and then immediately after I get the value "not-logged-in". I need to use this to hide/ show certain parts of my app if the user is logged in.

Normally if I use React without Redux I use this method all the time without any issues but can't understand what I might have done wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're not really assigning a value to newState in your reducer, so essentially you're returning `undefined`, which of course doesn't have a loginStatus property. Changing your reducer so to something like this will probably solve the problem:

```
let initialState = {
  loginStatus: "not-logged-in"
  , toggleRegLog: 'login'
};

const userAuthReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'loginUser':
    let newState;
    if (action.loggedIn) {
      newState = Object.assign({}, state, {
        loginStatus: "logged-in"
      })
    }
    else {
      newState = Object.assign({}, state, {
        loginStatus: "not-logged-in"
      })
    }
    return newState;
    break;
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
export default userAuthReducer;
```

Object.assign returns a new object, applies the data from `state` and the last argument containing the `loginStatus` property and passes that to the `newState` variable, which gets returned at the end of the switch case.

### Edit

This edit below makes it easier to reason about the logic in the reducer:

```
let initialState = {
  loginStatus: "not-logged-in"
  , toggleRegLog: 'login'
};

const userAuthReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'loginUser':
    if (action.loggedIn) {
      return Object.assign(state, { loginStatus: "logged-in" })
    }
    return Object.assign(state, { loginStatus: "not-logged-in" })
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
export default userAuthReducer;
```

Comment: so you're answer has half solved the problem. Now that I am returning a new object the state updates but I am still left with the issue of the initial state being undefined on component initial render. This is actually fixed with the if statement I have in the render: if(typeof(this.props.userAuthReducer) !== 'undefined' .... but I obviously would like to not have to do this for every bit of state I want to have in the render in my application...

Comment: could it be that you call `loginUser` action without the `loggedIn` property somewhere? I've added an example to my answer which would always return state with a `loginStatus` property, hope it helps.

Comment: Don't think there is, what's quite strange is if I add another case to the switch statement in the reducer I get the following console error: Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined. Not sure why this is? It really seems as though the initial state is not loading on componentDidMount but is on componenetDidUpdate...

Comment: But does the second snippet solve the error? It's there's no way for the reducer to return an 'empty' state in that snippet, I can hardly think of a scenario where that would fail